# Which dtype would be correct to prevent numpy.arange() from getting the wrong length?

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I am trying to get a shifting array containing 200 values in a range with a difference of 40.

Therefore i am using **`numpy.arange(a, b, 0.2)`** with starting values **`a=0`** and **`b=40`** and going upwards (**`a=0.2 b=40.2`**, **`a=0.4 b=40.4`** and so on).

When I reach **`numpy.arange(25.4, 65.4, 0.2)`** however I suddenly get an array with a length 201 values:

```
x = numpy.arange(25.2, 65.2, 0.2)
print(len(x))
```

Returns **200**

```
x = numpy.arange(25.4, 65.4, 0.2)
print(len(x))
```

Returns **201**

I got so far to notice that this happens probably due to rounding issues because of the data type...

I know there is a option 'dtype' in `numpy.arrange()`:

```
numpy.arange(star, stop, step, dtype)
```

The question is which data type would fit this problem and why? (I am not so confident with data types jet and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype hasn't helped me to get this issue resolved. Please help!

Comment: Would `np.linspace(0,40, 200)` accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: I believe that the `dtype` parameter here is just for telling numpy if the values in the array are strings, integers, floats, booleans, etc. So no, changing the `dtype` parameter wouldn't help you get the right length, you'd want to change the step.

Comment: As well thanks to you! Now I additionally have a deeper understanding of ´dtype´.

Comment: `arange` is most predictable with an integer step,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.arange` is most useful when you want to precisely control the **difference between adjacent elements**. `np.linspace`, on the other hand, gives you precise control over the **total number of elements**. It sounds like you want to use `np.linspace` instead:

```
import numpy as np

offset = 25.4

x = np.linspace(offset, offset + 40, 200)

print(x)
print(len(x))
```

Here's the documentation page for `np.linspace`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: That (obviously) did the trick. As I do wan't to have always 200 values, this indeed seems to be more appropriate (and working)! Thanks a lot!